# Make a Frozen Column look like a separate DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid, wpf-4.0

I have a DataGrid that i have frozen the first column. I am trying to to make the frozen column look like a separate DataGrid. I want to increase the grid line after the frozen column to look like the image below that i have made. I am not sure how to increase the grid line width after the frozen column.

[image]

```
  <DockPanel Name="dpHistory" LastChildFill="True" sl:UIAudit.Drsarea="SuperBillHistory">
<Border Background="Blue" Grid.Column="3"/>
<DataGrid Name="dgData" CanUserAddRows="False" 
          Style="{DynamicResource DataGridRow}" 
          CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                         CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                         IsReadOnly="True"
                         EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                         EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
                         AlternationCount="2"
                         AlternatingRowBackground="LightSteelBlue"
                         CanUserSortColumns="False"
                         FrozenColumnCount="2"
                          BorderThickness="5">       
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: I suggest amending your text so that it poses an explicit question.  Are you asking how to realize something like what your image suggests?  Or just how to add the 'gutter' to the right of the 'frozen column'?  Or something else?

Comment: Thanks for changing the title and text to make it clear.  Have you considered a horizontal stack panel laid out with:  DataGrid 1 (frozen column), then a WPF Rectangle with a gradient, then DataGrid 2.  All appearing together and giving the appearance of a single control?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but i am not sure how to add that. I was original thinking of only increasing the width of column one to make it look like a separate grid, but i have not had much luck

Comment: I know where you're coming from, and there may be a solution where the gutter is a template column with no header or rows.  But your current strategy looks like you will be on a safari to the templating jungle.  I suggest the stack panel approach first :)

Comment: can you please supply an example

Comment: That's easy enough to do, but I could only produce it in developer grey.  I.e., without the styling and colours you are using.  I would also not be able to populate the rows and columns as you have done.  Purely developer grey.  Would that be of any use at all?

Comment: yes that would be, it would give me something to go off of.

Comment: Done!  It's very prototypish, but will get you started

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to the strategy of making a single column 'frozen' and providing a pleasing gutter to its right, you can consider the strategy of using two datagrids separated by a gutter.  In that vein and following your comment that it would give you something to go off, here's some Xaml to look at...
[image]

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <system:Double x:Key="HeaderHeight">26</system:Double>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="GutterBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                <GradientStop Color="DarkGray" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <DataGrid Name="LeftMost"
                  Background="PaleTurquoise"
                  HeadersVisibility="Column"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding LeftHeaders}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
               <DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="False" CanUserResize="False">
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                       <TextBlock Height="{StaticResource HeaderHeight}" Text=""/>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="RosyBrown"/>
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource HeaderHeight}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <TextBlock Width="70" Text="{Binding .}" Background="LightBlue"/>
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Rectangle Width="5" Fill="{StaticResource GutterBrush}"/>
        <DataGrid Name="RightMost"
                  Background="PowderBlue"
                  GridLinesVisibility="All"
                  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 1" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource HeaderHeight}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 2" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource HeaderHeight}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column 3" >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource HeaderHeight}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This snippet has lots of different colours so that you can find which element does what more quickly.  But as shown, it's a Stack Panel containing two DataGrids and a Rectangle.  As mentioned above, you will need to separate your meticulous styling into two parts and apply them to the two DataGrids separately.  If you need to sync up the selection and/or scrolling, you can use binding, but that's another question for another day.  :)

Also, if you set the first DataGrid to CanUserResizeColumns, you can drag the size horizontally and give the effect of a splitter.

This approach gives the visual experience you are after and is a whole lot more straight-forward in implementation than the original.  Once the whole thing is implemented, you can probably go back and apply all the bits to a control template.  I will add this approach to my own bag of tricks.